# Problema con sympy en input

Tags: string, objeto, sympy, diff

intento hacer un pequeño y simple programa que reciba una función del usuario con un input y la derive, pero al usar su input con y.diff(x) me sale **str' object has no attribute 'diff'**

````
from sympy import Symbol
from scipy.misc import derivative
from sympy import *
from sympy import sympify

#Derivada
def derivar():
    x=Symbol('x')
    print("Usaremos x como variable, si tu función tiene otra, sustitúyela por x \n Ejemplo: 2*t**3 sería 2*x**3") 
    y=(input("Dame tu función (Recuerda usar bien los paréntesis y que los exponentes se escriben con ** \n Ejemplo: 2*x**3 se lee: Dos equis al cubo): "))
    derivada=sympify(y.diff(x))
    print("La derivada de ", y, "es \n", derivada)

derivar()```


 line 11, in derivar
    derivada=sympify(y.diff(x))
````

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo con tu código esto lo pude solucionar de dos formas:

1. Llama la función diff al término del sympify, de esta manera:

```
    def derivar():
       x = Symbol('x',real=True)
       print("Derivada de una función f(x): ")
       f1 = input ("2*x**3 de ejemplo")
       f2 = diff(sympify(f1))
       print("Función original: ", f1)
       print("Función derivada: ", f2)
    derivar()
```

2. Introduce la libreria de sympy "sympy.parsing.sympy_parser" al inicio de tus declaraciones, con lo cual tu expresión que inicialmente es un str, pasa a ser simbólica de acuerdo al método, quedando el programa así:

   ```
    Derivada
    def derivar():
       x=Symbol('x',real=True)
       print("Usaremos x como variable, si tu función tiene otra, sustitúyela por x \n 
       Ejemplo: 2*t**3 sería 2*x**3") 
       y=(input("Dame tu función (Recuerda usar bien los paréntesis y que los 
       exponentes se escriben con ** \n Ejemplo: 2*x**3 se lee: Dos equis al cubo): 
       "))
       ps=parse_expr(y,locals())
       derivada=diff(ps,x)
       print("La derivada de ", y, "es \n", derivada)
    derivar()
   ```